# testing flink jobs with MiniCluster to trigger the timer using processing time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

is there any way to control the processing time to **trigger** the **timer** when testing flink jobs with **MiniClusterWithClientResource**?

I'm able to test both the methods of the KeyedCoProcessFunction i.e. processElement()... triggering timer callback i.e onTimer()... in the **Unit Tests** using a **testharness** and controlling the processing time i.e:

//trigger processing time timer by advancing the processing time of the operator directly
testHarness.setProcessingTime(300000)

Thus. I can trigger the timer at the specified time

however, what I need now is trigger the timer in a end to end flink job test using minicluster **MiniClusterWithClientResource**

val flinkCluster = new MiniClusterWithClientResource...
and be able to advance the processing time to fire the onTimer method

Comment: adding a Thread.sleep(1000) one second in the SourceFunction class after all messages are sent solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

adding a Thread.sleep(1000) one second in the SourceFunction class after all messages are sent solved the problem.

```
class MySourceFunction() extends RichParallelSourceFunction[]{
...

//is a one-time Delay after all messages have been sent
Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```