# Function executes succesfully in production but not in test in Flink

Tags: java, testing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have written an integration test in Flink 1.12.3, which tests the `execute` method in StreamingJob class. Surprisingly, this method outputs records to sink succesfully in production environment, but it doesn't output anything in local tests. How can I solve this and enable testing?

[This may be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587105/testing-flink-jobs-with-minicluster-to-trigger-the-timer-using-processing-time)

````
    private static final DeviceIdSink deviceIdSink = new DeviceIdSink();
    
    @ClassRule
    public static MiniClusterWithClientResource flinkCluster =
            new MiniClusterWithClientResource(
                    new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
                            .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(1)
                            .setNumberTaskManagers(2)
                            .build());
    
    @Test
    public void testingAStreamingJob() throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(2);
        
        List<JsonNode> events = getListFromResource("events.json");
        DataStream<JsonNode> testStream = env.fromCollection(events);

        StreamingJob job = new StreamingJob(env, Time.seconds(60),
                 testStream, deviceIdSink);


        job.execute();

        System.out.println(deviceIdSink.values);


    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the `testStream` source is exhausted, the job will terminate. So if you have any time-based windowing happening, you'll have pending results that never get emitted.

I use a `MockSource` that doesn't terminate until the `cancel()` method is called, e.g.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.TypeSerializer;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.ResultTypeQueryable;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor;
import org.apache.flink.core.memory.DataInputView;
import org.apache.flink.core.memory.DataInputViewStreamWrapper;
import org.apache.flink.core.memory.DataOutputViewStreamWrapper;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * A very simple, non-parallel source based on a list of elements. You can specify a delay
 * for between each element that is emitted.
 * 
 * @param <T>
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MockSource<T> implements SourceFunction<T>, ResultTypeQueryable<T>, Serializable {
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MockSource.class);
    
    private int listSize;
    private byte[] elementsSerialized;
    private TypeInformation<T> typeInfo;
    private TypeSerializer<T> serializer;
    private Time delay = null;
    
    private transient volatile boolean running;

    // Constructor for cases where you want an empty list as the source.
    public MockSource(TypeInformation<T> typeInfo) throws IOException {
        this(Collections.emptyList(), typeInfo);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MockSource(T... elements) throws IOException {
        this((List<T>) Arrays.asList(elements));
    }

    /**
     * Create a source from <data>, which cannot be empty (if so, use the other constructor that takes a typeInfo
     * argument.
     * 
     * @param data
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MockSource(List<T> data) throws IOException {
        this(data, TypeExtractor.getForObject(data.get(0)));
    }

    public MockSource(List<T> data, TypeInformation<T> typeInfo) throws IOException {
        this.typeInfo = typeInfo;
        this.serializer = typeInfo.createSerializer(new ExecutionConfig());

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputViewStreamWrapper wrapper = new DataOutputViewStreamWrapper(baos);

        listSize = 0;
        try {
            for (T element : data) {
                serializer.serialize(element, wrapper);
                listSize++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Serializing the source elements failed: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        this.elementsSerialized = baos.toByteArray();
    }

    public MockSource<T> setDelay(Time delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
        return this;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<T> ctx) throws Exception {
        running = true;
        Object lock = ctx.getCheckpointLock();

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(elementsSerialized);
        final DataInputView input = new DataInputViewStreamWrapper(bais);

        int i = 0;
        while (running && (i < this.listSize)) {
            T next;
            try {
                next = serializer.deserialize(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to deserialize an element from the source. "
                        + "If you are using user-defined serialization (Value and Writable types), check the "
                        + "serialization functions.\nSerializer is " + serializer, e);
            }

            synchronized (lock) {
                ctx.collect(next);
                i++;
                
                if (delay != null) {
                    LOGGER.debug("MockSource delaying for {}ms", delay.toMilliseconds());
                    
                    Thread.sleep(delay.toMilliseconds());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<T> getProducedType() {
        return typeInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kkrugler. Is there a way to test entire StreamingJob that consists of time-based windowing that would wait until the stream is processed fully before everything terminates?

Comment: You can easily create a SourceFunction that doesn't exit from the run() method until after some AtomicBoolean is set. Setting that flag depends on your business logic, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Would you be so kind and present an example? I am not that experienced and I am still not sure how to do it.

Comment: Added example of testing source